# how to filter tableView cell on button click, if cell textField having string as of button name in swift

Tags: ios, swift, tablefilter

I want to filter the tableView cell on button click, show the cell if the cell's one element has the same string as that of button code. A Button is a collection view cell and all the buttons have some code. When I click on 1st button cell, the table needs to filter the cell having value as that of button code.

```
//Button UICollectionView 

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt 
     indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: 
       "buttonCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! SPCollectionViewCell


        // static cell
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            cell.zoneLbl?.text = "All"
            code = "00"
        }else{
            var item2 = self.zoneList[indexPath.row - 1]
            code = item2["ListID"] as? String
            cell.zoneLbl?.text = item2["ListName"] as? String
         }
       return cell
       }

//TableView

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "serviceProvider", for: indexPath ) as! serviceProviderTableViewCell

        let item = self.listData[indexPath.row]
        ZoneCategoryID =  item["ZoneCategoryID"]  as? String

        cell.serviceProviderName?.text = (item["CompanyName"] as? String)?.uppercased()
        cell.addressLbl?.text = item["Address"] as? String
        cell.emailLbl?.text = item["Email"] as? String
        cell.mobileNoLbl?.text = item["Phone"]  as? String
        zonee =  item["ListName"]  as? String
        TypeId = item["TypeID"]  as? String
        ServiceWellnessID =  item["ServiceWellnessID"]  as? String

       return cell
}
```

Here "code" value is same as "ZoneCategoryID".
Thanks in advance.